# BOOT FAILURE Prtition Change

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Stressed user here.  Last week I could not boot into my Ubuntu 5.04. I have now got the 14.04 installed via DVD. though I can not restore my backups and I have made matters even worse since I have changed the partitions which have stopped me using the FSCK command in the terminal. I can't get Ubuntu 15.04 back either.

I'm blind in both senses that I can't see what I'm doing and have to use my poor wife to carry out the operations and in the sense that I know little or nothing of restoring Ubuntu after boot failure and partition changing.  Totally, my fault about partition change.

Help before I damage the computer and ruin my marriage LOL
Andy :-(

Answer (score 0):

A few steps you can take. First install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS on a disk. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop boot from this disk, install on a flash drive! (recommend 32gb or above) You may need to partition the drive you can do this in the try Ubuntu link and use Gparted. Once install is complete reboot system. System comes with a update manager, run this after reboot or go into terminal and type "sudo apt-get update" then "sudo apt-get autoclean". You may also re-partition the systems hard-drive in gparted and install Ubuntu, but this must be done from flash not DVD! Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got that. So, I'll install Ubuntu via a Flash drive instead of the CD.  I have already got the CD with Ubuntu 14.04 which I have already installed.  So I'll have a go with a flash drive installation. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Install Ubuntu onto the partitioned flash drive; you may need to change the bios setting from fast boot, and change boot options to dvd/cd; usb; hard drive...

Comment: I lost my entire bootup and the newly installed Ubuntu 14.04.  I had no partitiions it was all unallocated now I have install 3 new partitions and have copied them below.

Comment: Partition Table: msdos 
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags 
 1      1049kB  13.6GB  13.6GB  primary  linux-swap(v1) 
 2      13.6GB  45.1GB  31.5GB  primary  ext4 
 3      45.1GB  120GB   74.9GB  primary  ext4            boot 
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0 has been opened read-only. 
Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!       @DnrDevil

Comment: Please use gparted to partition the flash drive and any other drive that you need too from the live cd. If you beed help with gparted http://m.wikihow.com/Use-Gparted Start with step 6

Comment: Hi There I now have a new situation where I cannot even boot into my Labtop via the Boot repair CD or the live Ubuntu DVD. I momentary get a Booting page for a second or so that goes blank. IS this the end? Is there life after blank screen? @DnrDevil

Answer (score 0):

Hi There I now have a new situation where I cannot even boot into my Labtop via the Boot repair CD or the live Ubuntu DVD.  I momentary get a Booting page for a second or so that goes blank.  IS this the end? Is there life after blank screen? @DnrDevil